# Meaning of "But the historical pattern of warfare remains inconclusive, frustrating, endlessly cyclical."

Tags: meaning

Here is a piece of text:

> But the historical pattern of warfare remains inconclusive, frustrating, endlessly cyclical. States persist in warfare because the mechanics of the balance of power rarely permit escape from it. [[link]](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2505515)

The first sentence confuses me (especially the words "inconclusive" and "frustrating"). Please tell me how you understand it? How can it be rephrased?

Comment: Please include the source of the quote.

Comment: "Inconclusive" here means it's hard to decide on or understand the pattern of war.

Comment: ...and a result, it is a frustrating task trying to define any such patterns.

Comment: Many-many thanks for comments and explanations!

Answer (score 1):

*"But the historical pattern of warfare remains inconclusive, frustrating, endlessly cyclical."*

this gives us

*"But the historical pattern of warfare is one that admits to there being no conclusion to war; the pattern is frustrating, and endlessly cyclical."*

which is

*"But the historical pattern of warfare is one that has no end; this pattern is frustrating, and repeats itself for ever."*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind assistance!